Physical interpretation of the expression for the tension in an Atwood Machine
In an Atwood Machine, the expression for the net acceleration of the system is
$$a=\frac{m_1-m_2}{m_1+m_2}g$$
and the expression for the tension in the string is
$$T=\frac{2 \ m_1 \ m_2}{m_1+m_2}g.$$
The former expression is fairly intuitive as it just says that the acceleration of the system equals the net driving force divided by the accelerating mass. Even in more complicated problems, I've been able to apply this concept successfully, albeit in more complex forms, or at the very least have my solutions match this form.
On the other hand, I have no clue how I should be interpreting the latter expression. Product of two masses makes no physical sense to me, and writing the expression in different forms has not been of any help either. The Wikipedia article of the Atwood Machine states that the mass factor is the harmonic mean of the two masses, but I'm unable to interpret that physically.
What I'm looking for is an explanation of the expression that would provide insight into what is happening physically the same way the expression for the acceleration does. Any attempts will be highly appreciated!
P.S. I've observed that in other, more complex problems, the tension still seems to have the form of product of masses in the numerator, and the same mass factor as the acceleration in the denominator (not necessarily just the sum of the masses), even when there are more than two masses.

Are you familiar with the use of free body diagrams?

@ChetMiller Yes I am.

Let's see your diagram(s).

@Salieri +1 Interesting question. Although there is already a good answer, I will still provide insight, albeit atypical, in a complete answer.

Building on the analogy of driving forces, the tension in the string can be understood as a struggle between the weights of mass $m_1$ and mass $m_2$, each trying to stretch the string apart in opposite directions.
If both masses were equal, i.e., $m_1 = m_2 = m$, then the string is pulled equally from both ends. The intensity of this pull is intuitively equal to the weight of either mass, i.e., $T = mg$.
This result is in accordance to the general formula for an Atwood machine. Now consider another case, where $m_1 = 2m$ and $m_2 = m$. Since $m_1$ is twice as heavy as $m_2$, the string will be accelerated in the direction of its weight.
Intuitively,  we feel like the tension should be something between $mg$ and $2mg$. This is because the heavier mass $m_1$ is pulling the string twice as hard (in terms of driving force) as the lighter mass $m_2$. This causes the string to accelerate, which "wastes" some of the tension that could be generated if it was balanced by an equal mass on the other end.
This tension cannot be equal to the arithmetic mean of $mg$ and $2mg$, i.e., $1.5mg$. To see why this is the case, consider the exaggerated example where $m_1 = 99m$ and $m_2 = m$. The arithmetic mean gives a tension of $50mg$. This doesn't seem right, because most of the driving force from $m_1$ goes into accelerating the string, with the tiny mass $m_2$ unable to stop it by with an opposing driving force.
The harmonic mean yields a more realistic tension value of $1.98mg$, which accounts for the effect of $m_1$, but only within reasonable limits. You can calculate the net force on $m_2$ to be $0.98mg$, making it accelerate at $0.98g$, i.e., almost equal to the acceleration of free-fall, but instead upwards.
The much heavier $m_1$ practically falls to the ground at $0.98g$, with the tiny $m_2$ unable to stop it. Our calculations are in line with our intuitions. Now, the final question.
Why exactly the harmonic mean? Why not something else? The reason lies in the following two equations:
$$m_1g - T = m_1a$$
$$T - m_2g = m_2a$$
Better written as:
$$g - \frac{T}{m_1} = a$$
$$\frac{T}{m_2} - g = a$$
Both accelerations being equal indicate the constraint of the string being inextensible.
We can think of this problem as a game of choosing a value of $T$ that suits both $m_1$ and $m_2$. If $T$ is too close to $m_1g$, then $m_1$'s acceleration becomes to small. If $T$ is too close to $m_2g$, then $m_2$'s acceleration becomes to small.
We need to choose a value of $T$ that considers both $m_1$ and $m_2$, with their weightage proportional to $1/m_1$ and $1/m_2$, i.e., the coefficients of $T$ in both equations. This sort of weighted average that considers the reciprocal of the terms is exactly what we call the harmonic mean!

Thanks for the beautiful answer! A lot of the ideas you've presented not only feel like they make sense to me, but have made other conceptual doubts I have click together and feel connected too. Each time I re-read your answer, I understand things a bit more and it just feels like a paradigm expansion.

As of now, the two ideas that have stood out to me the most are-
(i) Thinking of the net force the same way as I think of total mechanical energy, like a reserve. Some of the force goes into accelerating the masses/system, while the rest goes into interactive forces like tension force, normal force, etc.
In what proportions this force is distributed depends on the masses and their physical orientation in space.

(ii) Re-writing the two equations in the form of accelerations (by dividing by the mass) can be interpreted as a description of the constraints.
This is particularly helpful to me because further problems which include constraints, pseudo-forces, etc. have expressions of acceleration and tension that become exponentially harder to comprehend physically; they start to look like just solutions to the problem and not physical descriptions.

I will take some time to sit with these ideas, ponder on them, process them, connect them to other concepts, and think of how they apply to other problems. Thanks again!
PS: Is it possible to extend a question by adding more examples (with images) related to the original question?
If so, I would like to share my solutions of some other problems and just think about what the solution describes physically.

I'm glad you found my answer helpful! Of course, you could edit this same question to add more examples, but I think it would be better if you posted it as a separate question on the site and embedded the link to this one in it.
